# Como fazer 1 só consulta e distribuir o resultado espalhado pelo codigo?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

Bom tenho um site onde estou a cada area usando um select , ou seja acho que estou fazendo mais consultas do que devo, existe alguma maneira de repicar o resultado ? segue uma imagem do que estou proprondo

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
     <?php
     try {
     $sql = "SELECT * FROM anuncios ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 20";
       $stmt = $DB->prepare($sql);
       $stmt->bindValue(":Nid", intval($_GET["Nid"]));
       $stmt->execute();
       $results = $stmt->fetchAll();
    } catch (Exception $ex) {
      echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
    foreach ($results as $res) {
    $tipo = $res["tipo"];
    switch ($tipo) {
    case 'Imagem':
    echo "<div style='width:720px;height:90px'>
  <a href='".$res["codigo"]."' target='_blank'><img src='img/anuncios/".$res["Nid"]."/".$res["arquivo"]."' height='90' width='720'> </a>
  </div>";
    break;
    case 'Flash':
    echo "<div style='width:720px;height:90px'>
  <embed src='img/anuncios/".$res["Nid"]."/".$res["arquivo"]."' quality='high' pluginspage='http://www.macromedia.com/go/getflashplayer' type='application/x-shockwave-flash' height='90' width='720'> 
  </div>";
    break;
    case 'Codigo':
  echo "<div style='width:100%;height:100px'>
  ".$res["codigo"]."
  </div>";
    break;
    }
    } ?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Atribua os resultados numa variável. Normalmente num array. Com os dados numa variável, basta encaixá-los "onde quiser".

Veja um exemplo:

```
<?php
$dummy_data = array('anuncio a', 'anuncio b', 'anuncio c', 'anuncio d');
?>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>bla bla</td>
    <td colspan="2"><?php echo $dummy_data[0];?></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>lorem ipsum</td>
    <td><?php echo $dummy_data[1];?></td>
    <td>dumb lol</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>foo bar</td>
    <td><?php echo $dummy_data[2];?></td>
    <td><?php echo $dummy_data[3];?></td>
</tr>
<table>
```

No seu exemplo, nos trechos onde tem "echo", faria algo assim

```
    $ads[] = "<div style='width:720px;height:90px'>
  <a href='".$res["codigo"]."' target='_blank'><img src='img/anuncios/".$res["Nid"]."/".$res["arquivo"]."' height='90' width='720'> </a>
  </div>";
```

Então basta mandar imprimir:

```
bla bla <?php echo $ads[0];?> codigo html qualquer<br />
<?php echo $ads[1];?> lorem ipsum, outro texto qualquer.
```

Não está claro como pretende controlar isso, qual a quantidade de resultados que retornará e como pretende controlar onde deve imprimir cada um dos resultados.

Acho que o que pretende fazer é melhor com algo como o shortcodes do wordpress.

Tem uma library em JavaScript que simula a mesma funcionalidade: http://archive.nicinabox.com/shortcode.js/

Exemplo usando o shortcode.js

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js">/script>
<script src="http://archive.nicinabox.com/shortcode.js/src/Shortcode.js"></script>

<table border="1">
<tr>
    <td>bla bla</td>
    <td colspan="2">[ads0][/ads0]</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>lorem ipsum</td>
    <td>[ads1][/ads1]</td>
    <td>dumb lol</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>foo bar</td>
    <td>[ads2][/ads2]</td>
    <td>[ads3][/ads3]</td>
</tr>
<table>



</body>
</html>


<?php
$dummy_data = array('anuncio a', 'anuncio b', 'anuncio c', 'anuncio d');
?>

<script type="text/javascript">
new Shortcode(document.querySelector('body'), {
<?php

/**
Aqui damos 20 voltas independente da quantidade de resultados provinda do banco de dados. O limite de 20 é baseado no script da pergunta onde o `LIMIT` é 20.
*/

for ($i = 0; $i < 20; $i++) {
?>
    ads<?php echo $i;?>: function(done) {
        return '<?php echo (isset($dummy_data[$i])?$dummy_data[$i]:'');?>';
    },
<?php
}
?>
});
</script>
```

Comment: nesse caso entao em cada resultado teria que usar o switch certo? pois preciso separar antes o tipo de cada um , não seria possivel ja pegar fazer toda essa verificacao e colocar o resultado dentro de outra array?

Comment: Pelo que entendi do código que postou, o switch é necessário devido ao tipo do banner. Pois pode ser texto, imagem ou flash. Esse switch tem que manter. Mas o foco em questão é sobre como imprimir os anúncios no meio dos textos e html da página, certo?

Comment: ta certinho sim, vou fazer outra pergunta sendo mais detalhista